# GLSL - Equivalent Of "layout (location = 1)" In #version 130

Tags: layout, compatibility, glsl

I am reading a tutorial about openGL 3.3 (where naturally GLSL 330 is in use). Unfortunately my hardware is limited to openGL 3.0 (where GLSL 130 is the newest format). In GLSL 130 the syntax

```
layout (location = 1) in vec4 position;
```

produces an error. Most importantly a code where several instances of "layout" are applied to different variables does not work. I even tried

```
#extension ARB_explicit_attrib_location : require
```

which is also not supported. Is there a way to rewrite these statements from 330 in 130 equivalently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your implementation does not support ARB_explicit_attrib_location (either as an extension or as `version 330` or later), then you cannot use explicit attribute locations. You must specify them before the linking phase with [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml).

And technically, your "hardware" could do this just fine. NVIDIA and ATI support this extension in all hardware that they still support in drivers. This is an API convenience. I'm guessing you're on some from of Intel hardware. If so, you have my sympathy.

BTW, is that [my code, by chance](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/)?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That is the tutorial I'm doing! =)
Wow! To think, that I'd meet the creator in the wide www. 
As a little feedback:
I could not get the framework in your tutorial to create a window. It gives errors in code::blocks and simply shows no window in vs2010. I am using a different openGL context i found somewhere else. I just copy anything important for the specific tutorials there and it works. Apart from that - the explanations in your tutorial are great!!

Comment: BTW. My hardware is ATI Radeon HD 3200 - a on board card in a HP Pavilion tx 2000 laptop. Maybe '#extension ARB_explicit_attrib_location : require' is a slightly false syntax? In any case the console says it is not supported.

Comment: @Fejwin: Laptop drivers tend to not be supported by the GPU makers, so you have to live with the older versions. I actually do a lot of coding an testing on a Radeon HD3300 integrated desktop GPU. I'd be interested in taking a look at your Code::Blocks compile error (Premake4 only seems to supports GNU-based Code::Blocks builds, so that may be the cause). You can file a bug report over on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/wiki/Home).

Comment: Alright! I will definitely send a bug report later this day - but somehow I cannot find the "file bug report" button over there on Bitbucket. Maybe I'm blind, could you tell me where exactly to submit my written comments on that page? ^^

Comment: What if my shader is written in #version 130, then compiled and distributed with my exe - would someone with a openGL version <3.0 be able to execute my program correctly? (I figure, since it is already compiled, the routines are somehow the same with the old syntax.)
btw. I still cannot find the "submit bug report" option at Bitbucket.

Comment: @Fejwin: You cannot distribute compiled shaders; as you may have noticed, shader compilation is a one-way street. You give it to OpenGL, and you get an opaque object back. And in Bitbucket, bugs are a type of "issue".

Comment: Ah, I see. So better stick with the lowest GLSL version possible. Thank you for glBindAttribLocation! Worked like a charm. I will post a bug report in the next hour.